# How to move and size \colorbox

Tags: box

\Colorbox creates a box of color, right? Simple question: How can I control the size and the positioning of \colorbox (if possible in cm) ?

Additionally: can even the shape of colorbox be adjusted?

Comment: `\colorbox` is meant to put a box around something. That something can be blank, and therefore allow you to draw coloured boxes. However, if you're interested in arbitrary shapes, you're better off going with a graphics package.

Comment: Considering using [tcolorbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en)

Comment: what kind of graphic-packages actually? All I want to do is to create a rectangle of a desired color and move and squish it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\colorbox` simply draw a background rectangle with the width and height of what is inside plus a margin around that is equal to `\fboxsep`. You can control the size and  shape of the box setting `\fboxsep` and/or including anything taking some vertical and/or horizontal size, as text, another boxes, minipages, tabulars, etc.

The position can be controlled in the same way that you control the position any character. If you can move a  "A" in some form, you can do the same with a color box of the same size. That is, there are nearly infinite ways to do it.

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep2pt
\colorbox{red!40}{C} 
\fboxsep2em
\colorbox{red!40}{o} 
\fboxsep2pt
\colorbox{red!40}{\rule[-4em]{0pt}{4em} l} 
\colorbox{red!40}{\rule[1em]{0pt}{2em} o} 
\colorbox{red!40}{\makebox[4em][l]{r}} 
\raisebox{1em}{\rotatebox{45}{\fboxsep1ex\colorbox{blue!40}{\rotatebox{-45}{b}}}}\kern-1em%
\rotatebox[origin=tr]{15}{\fboxsep0pt\colorbox{blue!40}{\rotatebox{-15}{\makebox[2em][c]{o}}}}
\colorbox{blue!40}{\strut x} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess this answers my question fairly well. But isn't there a more simple way? For instance I can control easily {textblock}{Width}(x,y). The Reason being is that I actually want to draw a frame around my blocks just by adding a rectangle behind it.

Comment: @NessLange Well,  LaTeX is a macro language, i.e., it lets you define your own commands to simplify  code. Or you can use an already made macro provided for some packages. But the first is know what you want to do exactly, that still is not clear to me. To provide concrete solutions we must see  a concrete scenario  (a  document as minimal as possible, but compilable, not a chunk of code)  and a clear explanation of how you want to modify it.

Comment: I found that something like \begin{textblock}{0}(1.5,2)
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[draw=black,fill=orange] (10.5,6) rectangle (0,0);
\filldraw[draw=black,fill=blue] (10.5,6) rectangle (9.75,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{textblock} is completely sufficient